Migration of image hosting from Imgur to Stack Exchange - now live
Just a heads-up: Stack Exchange has chosen our site to be one of the early adopters of the new Stack Exchange image hosting.
For background, the official announcement of the transition of image hosting from Imgur to Stack Exchange's own hosting was here on the main Meta:
Stack Exchange’s image hosting arrangement with Imgur is ending - advance notice
We're told there should be no change in functionality with the new image hosting. It is already live on our main site (not here on our Meta, from what I just tested). So on our main site, you will see that image uploads now go to i.sstack.net instead of i.stack.imgur.com.
It should just work :) But if you see any bugs related to using the new image hosting, please post a new question here on our Meta including a detailed report (please include date/time, any error messages, what you were trying to do, what actually happened etc.) with the tags bug and image-hosting-migration-2024. We will add the required moderator-only tag (status-review) to alert Stack Exchange staff.

You will see the CircuitLab schematic editor still uploads its images to i.stack.imgur.com. This was already raised in the earlier Meta question here:
Impact on CircuitLab schematic integration of moving from Imgur to a different image hosting service
and Voltage Spike kindly alerted Stack Exchange about that post at the time.
Today, Stack Exchange said they have not yet settled on the timetable for updating the CircuitLab integration.

Here are some related posts on Meta.SE about this change, which might be interesting:

Remove the 160px minimum image size limit on Stack Exchange internal image hosting (thanks to Chester Gillon)
sstatic.net images aren't displayed on (some?) other sites outside the SE network
What changes were introduced in the new image uploader, and are not considered bugs?
Images from i.sstatic.net only work for me after being accessed from another IP address
The new image uploader is slower than the old image uploader


I just ran into the issue that a minimum image size in pixels seems to have been imposed on image uploads, in that the minimum image size now seems to be 160x160px. Found Remove the 160px minimum image size limit on Stack Exchange internal image hosting has already been created on the main meta site, so added an answer on that meta question.

@ChesterGillon - Many thanks for the info. I see that SE staff are aware of that bug report and have tagged it for investigation. Therefore adding your info in an answer there, rather than creating a new bug report here, makes sense. || As we see from info there, the image upload is disallowed if either dimension is <160 px and a screen capture of a few lines from a datasheet, as you did, could certainly hit that restriction :(

I feel like "Stack Exchange said they have not yet settled on the timetable for updating the CircuitLab integration." really means something more like "Stack Exchange forgot to consider CircuitLab integration" ... ;)

@brhans - Hi, I understand that concern. I hope it isn't / wasn't true :(

@ChesterGillon - Hi, FYI the 160x160px minimum size limitation has now been removed - please see this answer on the topic where you posted.
